# Copying a 32 bit integer to a 64 bit integer is undefined?

Tags: c, int

Well, I know `<< 32` is undefined on 32-bit integers... I also know pointer casts and dereferences don't mix much.

But this one is kind of none of them.

test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint64_t tmp = 1 << 31;
    printf("%" PRIx64 "\n", tmp);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I do this:

```
$ gcc test.c -o test
$ ./test
ffffffff80000000
```

Why did it corrupt the first 4 bytes?

Lower shifts work fine.
If I do `printf("%x\n", 1 << 31)`, it yields 80000000 as expected.
If tmp is 32 bits, it also works fine.

`u64` and `__u64` also have this quirk.

Comment: Oops... I almost forgot: sizeof(unsigned int) returns 4.

Comment: That "corruption" is actually [sign extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension).

Comment: `1 << 31` causes undefined behaviour

Comment: @MattMcNabb That is... odd. Could you please post a source?

Comment: Yes, see the description of the left-shift operator in the C standard (in C11 it is 6.5.7/4).  It is undefined because 2 to the power of 31 is not representable in a signed int.

Comment: Oh, I see. I keep missing the part where it's signed. Thank you `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't corrupt anything, but you also didn't shift a 64-bit number. In C, a single `1` defaults to `int`. If you want to use `1` as an `unsigned long` (or `unsigned`), tell the compiler by suffixing the number with (`UL` or `U` -- (`ULL` on **x86**)), otherwise you are shifting a signed number:

```
uint64_t tmp = 1ULL << 31;
```

**Output**

```
80000000
```

Comment: :) Geez. I've been assuming for such a long time that left shifting is somehow an inherently unsigned operation, since it still doesn't make sense to me otherwise. Thank you; I'm waiting for Stack Overflow to let me accept an answer.

Comment: We have all puzzled over that one, me included, until someone enlightens us `:p`

Comment: Perhaps better, since you know you want a `uint64_t` result, but you don't know which predefined type that is: `uint64_t tmp = (uint64_t)1 << 31;` -- or even `uint64_t tmp = UINT64_C(1) << 31;`